# Reduce redundant code

Tags: java, java-ee-6

It's starting to feel redundant that I have to specify the doGet parameters and what it throws every time.  Is there a way to do all of that within my `Controller` so it doesn't have to be done on every page?  My `Controller` currently has no `doGet()`

```
@WebServlet(name = "EditServlet", urlPatterns = {"/content/edit"})
public class EditServlet extends cms.library.Controller {
    @Override
    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        this.loadView(new cms.library.PageConfig()
                .setRequest(request)
                .setResponse(response)
                .setTemplate("/content/edit"));
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("posted");

        this.doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "not having a `doGet`" since there's a `doGet`. Also, I'm not sure it's reasonable to equate POSTs with GETs; it would almost certainly be a client error to POST to something that isn't form-ish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in the template to the cms.library.Controller class so you don't have to define doGet everytime.

```
public class Controller {
    private final String template;
    public Controller( String template ) {
        this.template = template;
    }
    @Override
    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.loadView(new cms.library.PageConfig()
                .setRequest(request)
                .setResponse(response)
                .setTemplate(template));
    }
}

@WebServlet(name = "EditServlet", urlPatterns = {"/content/edit"})
public class EditServlet extends cms.library.Controller {
    public EditServlet() {
        super("/content/edit");
    }
    @Override
    public void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("posted");
        this.doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Or you could make your own annotation and the `Controller` class would inspect the implementing class in its constructor for the annotation (instead of passing in the string).